# nginx rewrite all trailing / to /index.html with proxy pass

Tags: nginx

Using nginx as a reverse proxy, I'd like to mimic the `index` directive with `proxy_pass`. Therefore I'd like nginx to query `/index.html` instead of `/`, `/sub/index.html` instead of `/sub/`.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Not sure if it's relevant, but the proxied server does answer `HTTP 200` on `/`, but I'd still like to rewrite it to `/index.html`.

As the `/` request leaks some information by listing the directory content, I'd also like to be sure that no one will be capable of accessing it (like doing something like `/sub/..`).

Thanksies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add :

```
rewrite (.*)/$ $1/index.html last;
rewrite (.*)/..$ $1/../index.html last;
```

Should works